# How to Restrict Members wont see admin_page.php using session

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have registered sessions by using an array containing: username, password and role.
Now I don't want to show the administrator page to whomever enters to the site as member.
How can I restrict admin_home.php using session>

This is my code:

**-> login_check.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include('connect.php');
$name = $_POST['name'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$role = $_POST['member'];
$sql = "select * from login_register where name =
'$name' and password = '$password' and role = '$role'";
$retain = mysql_query($sql, $con);
$count=mysql_num_rows($retain);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($retain);
if($count == 1){
$_SESSION['User'] = array('name' => '$name', 'password' => 
'$password' , 'role' => '$member');
if ( $role == "admin"){
header("location:admin_home.php");}
else  if ( $role == "member"){
header("location:member_home.php");}}
else {
echo  "<a href='index.php'>click here to login   </a>";}
?>
```

**-> member_home.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['User'])){
header('location:index.php');
}
```

**-> admin_home.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['User']))
{
header('location:index.php');
}
?>
```

I don't want to allow members, under any circumstance to enter **admin_home.php**

Also my MySQL fields: id, username, password, role should change only if any changes is made in my database. Please tell me how can I implement that.

I have already wasted 2 days on this and I can't figure it out. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the session name..try this

change in login_check.php

```
<?php
if ( $role == "admin")
{

$_SESSION['adminuser']=$_POST['name'];
header("location:admin_home.php");
}
else  if ( $role == "member")
{
header("location:member_home.php");
$_SESSION['user']=$_POST['name'];
}
```

?>

change in  member_home.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
header('location:index.php');
}
?>
```

change in  admin_home.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['adminuser']))
{
header('location:index.php');
}
?>
```

try something like this

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $variab;// array variable
print_r($_SESSION['name'][0]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ezhil you gave me a good solution ... i wasted 2days for this ., now going to take a coffee wow.. now the member cant view admin_home.php page .. thanks a lot ....  in addition can u try to give me a code with sessions as a array pls

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Please mask this answer as solution (green check).

Comment: ya i marked this as answer .. and its 100% working man .. thank you very much

Comment: Hi.,
i found one thing ., for the first time member login can able to view the admin page
second time he wont .

Answer (score 0):

You can change third line on admin_home.php as follow

```
 if (!isset($_SESSION['User']) || $_SESSION['User']['role'] != 'admin')
```

Best regards,
Nebojsa

Comment: Thank you very much Nebojsa ., now member can't able to view admin_home.php page., but while im login in as a admin also i can't view the admin_home .php ., see i have login page with username : and password : and select role:  k if i have login as member i dont view admin page ., if i login as admin i can view admin page this is my actual need..

Comment: What is value of $_POST['member'] for admin user?